# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, class, swift3

I am very new to swift development and I am working on [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1) of an apple provided swift tutorial. I created an outlet for a label, image, and custom view that are nested in a Table Cell. When I run I get this error

> 2016-07-20 23:16:11.110 FoodTracker[8446:3016336] Unknown class MealTableViewCell in Interface Builder file.
>   2016-07-20 23:16:11.124 FoodTracker[8446:3016336] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

There are no duplicate outlets and I believe the cellIdentifier used in my Table View Controller is correct.
My table cell

```
import UIKit

class MealTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//    MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}}
```

My Table View Controller

```
import UIKit

class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {
// MARK: Properties

var meals = [Meal]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadSampleMeals()
}

func loadSampleMeals() {
    let photo1 = UIImage(named: "meal1")!
    let meal1 = Meal(name: "Caprese Salad", photo: photo1, rating: 4)!

    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "meal2")!
    let meal2 = Meal(name: "Chicken and Potatoes", photo: photo2, rating: 5)!

    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "meal3")!
    let meal3 = Meal(name: "Pasta with Meatballs", photo: photo3, rating: 3)!

    meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return meals.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
    cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
    cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating

    return cell
}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set class of RatingControl in storyboard??

Answer (score 10):

Check for a broken outlet link in your storyboard file. Find your controller and `control`-click on the yellow circle above its nib to open the actions and outlets popover. You should see an outlet for `nameLabel` with a yellow warning sign. Either reconnect it to your controller's file or remove it if its a duplicate.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple , the story board can not find the outlet with the name "nameLabel". So either create a label by that name or delete the reference of the created label from the storyboard.

Here are the steps

Just click the storyboard and select the last Tab.[image]

Now search for the nameLabel and click on cross to disconnect.
All the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must link your `UITableView` from your interface builder to your `MealTableViewController` class ( `Ctrl` + `drag` )

Then, in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `MealTableViewController` class, you must register your custom cell class to your table view :

`self.tableView.registerClass(MealTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MealTableViewCell")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried this and now my cell is being returned when i call "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" but its properties are nil and I cannot figure out why. The outlets for them are setup properly